# Выводить разные iframe в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, php, css, iframe

Например, если экран > 800, то выводить iframe1. В противном случае выводить iframe2.

**Обновление**

Прошу прощения, у меня сейчас есть div, в который выводит при любом разрешении iframe1, мне нужно сделать, если ширина >800 (например, разрешение экрана 1280 x 1024), чтобы выводило iframe2.
Подскажите, пожалуйста. :)

**Обновление 2**

Я предполагаю, что Media здесь не достаточно, так как с помощью него можно  менять только стили css, а мне нужно менять iframe, а не его стиль, но если я ошибаюсь, буду признателен, если вы меня направите на правильный путь. :)

Comment: А в чём вопрос? Вы сделали, но у вас не выводит? Представьте свой код. :)

Comment: Будьте добры, воспользуйтесь сервисом http://jsfiddle.com  
Выложите свой код. Это ускорит получение ответа.

Comment: А что media css не используете?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что Media здесь не достаточно, так как с помощью него можно  менять только стили css, а мне нужно менять iframe, а не его стиль, но если я ошибаюсь, буду признателен, если вы меня направите на правильный путь:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/vL85rntb/1/), окно с iframe порастягивайте и посжимайте (сделал 600, чтобы удобнее было смотреть), грузятся 2 разные страницы, правда, периодически страница сваливается на Forbidden, наверное, сервер не хочет, чтобы к нему так грубо обращались, но страницу выдаёт нужную стабильно. Вот код скрипта:

```
// Функция для определения размера окна браузера и подстановки нужного фрейма
function changeFrame() {
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (width > 600) {
        window.frames['id_frame'].src = "http://hashcode.ru/";
    } else {
        window.frames['id_frame'].src = "http://hashcode.ru/questions/375553/";
    }
}

// Вызов функции
changeFrame();

// Вызов функции при ресайзе окна браузера
window.onresize = function(event) {
    changeFrame();
};
```